# Using SQL Server database for login control instead of default ASPNETDB.mdf database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use a SQL Server database as opposed to the default database (`ASPNETDB.mdf`) for login credentials for an ASP.NET web application I am building. I found and ran `aspnet_regsql.exe` which populated the database with the correct tables, but how do I point change where all of the default login controls point? After doing research I feel I probably have to do something to the `App_Data` folder or `web.config` file but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Have you read up on (custom) Membership Providers? Your question seems a little Db oriented, the problem isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the connection property string in the membership section in the web configuration to use what ever database connection from the database connection string section like :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="membershipConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ALGHABBAN-DEV;Initial Catalog=TimeTable;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>

 <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="membershipConnectionString" applicationName="/" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

notes the connectionStringName property  in the membership section is using membershipConnectionString in the connection string section ..

I hope this answer will help you ..

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "database connection string", as I supposed to put the path to my database after name=? Is this something I do in C#?

Comment: if you take a look at the membership setting there will be property name connectoinString this one will take the name of you the connection string the you declare in the connection string section here more details : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89029/Using-SQL-Membership-with-ASP-NET-application